# YouTube API in ASP.NET - play video, search by title

Tags: asp.net, api, youtube-api

I would like to play a video on my ASP.NET Webpage, but I have no clue how to pull this off and I don't understand anything about the YouTube API. I'm clueless when it comes to API's

But what I want to achieve is the following:

when I click on a button (trailer), I take the title of the movie/game and search with it in the YouTube database (or something like that). And the best (or first or idk) found video will be the one playing on my webpage.

For example:

I have a page with all the details on the movie "Iron Man", when I click on the button "Trailer", I'd like to play the trailer from the movie Iron Man on my webpage.

Is this possible, if yes, how do I do this?
I can't provide code, because I have no clue how to even begin with this. I just have a button and a label with the title as text. That's it ..

If someone can help me out, please explain it very detailed so I can maybe understand it.

Thanks in advance! You'd me helping me out big time!

Comment: It will be difficult to provide you with all the help you need, but I think you just need to read through the API documentation, and look up some tutorials or code samples. I know for me, seeing an actual sample can really help with understanding how to use the APIs. Here is a [.Net sample provided in the YT API documentation for searching by keyword](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#search_by_keyword), that might get you moving in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some simple javascript and html i wrote that allows the user to bring in a youtube video when searched hope it helps.

let me know here is the fiddle aswell

-http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/qn4C7/

html

```
<input type="text" id="Search"  /><br/>
<input id="show" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="Show();"/>

<div id="result">

</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#show").click(function () {
        getYoutube($("#Search").val() + "Offical Film Trailer");
    });
});

function getYoutube(title) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: yt_url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=' + title + '&format=5&max-results=1&v=2&alt=jsonc',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.data.items) {
                $.each(response.data.items, function (i, data) {
                    var video_id = data.id;
                    var video_title = data.title;
                    var video_viewCount = data.viewCount;
                    var video_frame = "<iframe width='600' height='385' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + video_id + "' frameborder='0' type='text/html'></iframe>";
                    var final_res = "<div id='title'>" + video_title + "</div><div>" + video_frame + "</div><div id='count'>" + video_viewCount + " Views</div>";
                    $("#result").html(final_res);
                });


            } else {
                $("#result").html("<div id='no'>No Video</div>");
            }
        }
    });
}
```